# Neos flow news Package

Tags: package, neoscms

i looking for a complete News Package like typo3 news , that working with current neos 3.1? 
Has someone experience or ideas where i can find it?

I have already searched in neos package list and on github, but all packages are not compatibel with neos 3.1.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources if off topic on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Neos is working differently as TYPO3.
In Neos you can make your own News Plugin with only a few lines of code.

But still, there are some functionalities which are always needed and there for is https://github.com/Flowpack/Flowpack.Listable

News, Articles, ... are nothing different as a list of Pages and this package helps you with the this stuff.

There is also a good video about this topic from a core developer on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q44mpQX8eWU

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks, I have already found the Listable Package and the youtube Video.
Additional i found this Thread: https://discuss.neos.io/t/no-news-plugin/2203 !
But: I am looking for a complete package instead of coding my own News Package.